# Wordpress/Wishlist Member if foreach else loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a moment of brain freeze. I have the following code working with a custom SQL query to show all upcoming posts on a membership site running Wishlist Member, based on a member's join date:

```
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
if ($pageposts) {
global $post;
    foreach ($pageposts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $postDate = strtotime($post->post_date);
    $todaysDate = strtotime(now);
        if ($postDate > $todaysDate) {
        echo '<li>';  
        echo the_title();
        echo '</li>';
        }
        else {
        // Do nothing for now
        }
      }
    }
```

The variable $pageposts is always populated, but links only show to members if there are pages available in the future to members within Wishlist's content scheduler. My question is - if there are no further posts for members according to the scheduler how do I echo something to the effect 'No further posts available' outside of the foreach loop? Have searched, but nothing quite matches up for me. Thanks.

Comment: shouldnt it be `if(count($pageposts) <= 0)`?

Comment: Use some flag & change it if ever goes in your first if condition,than you can check the same once your loops gets over.

Comment: or set a counter at the beginning = 0 and do an incrementation in the echo-block. At the end if the counter is 0 then you can output your message

Comment: Thanks for your input @steven - the problem I have is that $pageposts always contains the same array of 14 Wordpress posts and is never empty, I just want to echo something when there are no future posts according to the scheduler. I think I understand what you are saying with regard to a counter in the echo block, but would you be kind enough to point me in the direction of an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$counter = 0; // setup a counter with initial value = 0
if ($pageposts) {
    global $post;
    foreach ($pageposts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $postDate = strtotime($post->post_date);
        $todaysDate = strtotime(now);
        if ($postDate > $todaysDate) {
            echo '<li>';  
            echo the_title();
            echo '</li>';
            $counter++;  // increment of $counter (+1)
        }
    }
}
if($counter == 0) {  // if counter was not incremented, you know that there were no post 
    echo 'no posts!';
}
```